# How to prevent "install java" popups

Tags: safari, install, java

When I browse certain websites in Safari, I am frequently met with popups with instructions on how to install Java. But I don't want to install Java, especially not the plugin. How do I tell Safari to shut up about it?

Comment: Usually a missing plugin is [indicated with a button](http://i.imgur.com/LpuGrUt.png) and doesn't trigger a pop-up unless you click it. The websites you visit might just be programmed to show a pop-up if java is not detected in your browser. In that case you should look into disabling pop-ups.